# Is it possible to use custom font as math font?

Tags: pdftex, truetype

I can use a custom truetype font (e.g. georgia) as main font in pdflatex thanks to [this tutorial](http://starlinq.livejournal.com/3396.html).

Now, I want to use this font as math font for the entire document. Is it possible?

Note: I don't care if some symbols are missing or not, I just want to use this font in mathematical statements.

Comment: You should take a look at the `mathastext` package

Comment: @Bernard That is definitely what I was looking for. Thank you. I'll accept as answer if you write one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the `mathastext` package, which is done for that.

From the documentation:

> The mathastext package changes the fonts which are used in math mode for letters, digits
>   and a few other punctuation and symbol signs to replace them with the font as used for the
>   document text.