# Using body font in formulae

Tags: fonts, fontspec, mathastext

In Short: I can change the math font, but it is not working for numbers.

My document has a few formulae but only basic alphanumeric characters with very limited symbols (square root being the only particular character outside of the most common)

I have looked at the following questions:

- [Mathastext: Wrong digits in math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444565/mathastext-wrong-digits-in-math-mode)
- [Is it possible to use custom font as math font?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408801/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-font-as-math-font)

And have gotten this far using the `mathastext` package (I'm on v1.3w):

[image]

I have made sure to load `mathastext` *after* `fontspec`.

But, while letters show as expected, numbers still have serifs.

**Constraints:**

- I am compiling with LuaLatex due to other packages in the mix

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{RUBIK-REGULAR}[
    Path=fonts/,
    Extension=.ttf
]
\usepackage{mathastext}
\begin{document}
    \[T=2\sqrt{\frac{D}{A}}\]
    \center{Body Text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{RUBIK-REGULAR}[
%    Path=fonts/,
%    Extension=.ttf
%]
\setmainfont{Impact} % a random distinctive font on my system
\usepackage{mathastext}


\begin{document}

\[T=2\sqrt{\frac{D}{A}}\]

\begin{center}Body Text\end{center}

\end{document}
```

By the way, the command `\center` exists but

- it has no argument
- it should only be used implicitly via the `center` environment

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. The `\center` was just to create the sample image, I should have removed it from my MWE, apologies for any confusion it may have caused.

Answer (score 3):

You could also load

```
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
```

And set the fonts to something like (if you’ve added a `Rubik.fontspec` file to your project directory):

```
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmainfont{Rubik}[Scale=1.0]
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont{Rubik}[range=up]
```

You can add to this any other characters the Rubik font contains, either with a hex code like `"FF`, a macro name, or a backtick literal.  You can also do ranges, so if the font supports all of Latin-1, you could write `range={up,"20-"FF}`.

If the font you select does not have Greek letters, use instead:

```
\setmathfont{Rubik}[range=up/{Latin,latin,digits}]
```

Comment: I have seen "fone" into your answer and after I have understood that the word is font 

Comment: Nice, if I understand correctly, this would give me total granularity to have a specific character or set of characters in a specific font for formulae ? (That's much more than I need for this specific case but a nice tool to keep in the bag for later. - Thanks!)

Comment: @agryson Yes. You can also apply any other transformation from `fontspec`, such as changing their color.